# Iterative uniform recombination of integer lists in python with numba

Tags: python, performance, numba

I have a list of `N` integers and I iteratively take two integers at random, which are not at the same position in the list and uniformly recombine their binary representation, e.g. in `intList = [1,4,1,5]` `(N=4)` the number on the second and third position is chosen, aka `4 & 1`, and their binary represenations `4=100` & `1=001` is uniformly recombined. Uniformly recombined means that I chose either the `1 or the 0` of the first position, one of the two `0's` of the second position and either the `0 or 1` of the third position. This could result in 000 or 101 or 100 or 001. The result is saved as integer in the list. In each iteration I do this recombination for all `N` integers. This happens in a function with a numba decorator. My code is:

```
@nb.njit()
def comb():
    iterations = 100000
    N = 1000
    intList = list(range(N))   # this is just an example of possible integer lists
    l = 10   # length of the largest binary representation. 
    intList_temp = [0]*N
    for _ in range(iterations):
        for x3 in range(N):
            intList_temp[x3] = intList[x3]
        for x3 in range(N):
            randint1 = random.randint(0, N - 1)
            randint2 = random.randint(0, N - 1)
            while randint1 == randint2:
                randint1 = random.randint(0, N - 1)
                randint2 = random.randint(0, N - 1)
            a = intList[randint1]
            b = intList[randint2]
            c = a ^ ((a ^ b) & random.randint(0, (1 << l) - 1))
            intList_temp[x3] = c
        for x3 in range(N):
            intList[x3] = intList_temp[x3]
    return intList

print(timeit(lambda: comb(), number=1))
>>>2.59s
```

My question is, can this be improved?

Comment: Are you sure the code works? `(1 << l)` throws `l is undefined`

Comment: my mistake, `l` should be the length of the binary representation of the largest integer. If you choose  `l` to be 10 in my example code it should work.

Comment: The numbers in intList are chosen, such that they are equal or smaller than `l` but I think that is not important.

Comment: asked this on the answer I took down, is the output supposed to be a  list of the same number repeated 1000 times?

Comment: In each iteration, we choose for each entry two random variables, which are recombined as described above. The update process is sequential and that is the reason why I create intList_temp. Did I make myself more clear? Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Actually sequential might be the wrong word for that but I hope it is still clear. Let me know otherwise.

Comment: I'm asking if the expected output of that process is supposed to a list repeating a single number. For example I just copy-pasted it into a fresh file and when I run `comb()` it returns `1013` repeated 1000 times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116690/discussion-between-coupcoup-and-highwayjohn).

Comment: Okay I understand. The only reason you get a single number 1000 times is, that the process was repeated 100000 times and by chance all other numbers got lost. In my code other things are also happening in each iteration and then the result is not like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No significant performance improvement but cleaner code.

Because `temp_list` is overwritten element-wise you can create it once and then leave it. At the end of each iteration you can then copy the entire list into `int_list` for the next iteration.

Similarly you can simplify creating the random ints `a` and `b` a bit. There are a lot of ways that get close to this in numpy but nothing I can find that beats the naive sampling directly works with numba and numba beats any overall solution I can think of without it.

Unfortunately (or maybe fortunately depending on your view), the numba compiler is compiling it down to the best solution I can think of for both your original version and this. Only difference is readabilitiy:

```
@nb.njit()
def comb(int_list, l, iterations):
    n = len(int_list)

    temp_list = int_list

    for _ in range(iterations):
        for i in range(n):
            a, b = 0, 0
            while a == b:
                a = random.randint(0, n - 1)
                b = random.randint(0, n - 1)

            temp_list[i] = a ^ ((a ^ b) & random.randint(0, l))

        int_list = temp_list

    return int_list

print(timeit(lambda: comb(list(range(1000)), (1 << 10) - 1, 100000), number=10))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The numba decorator is kinda necessary, since other stuff is also happening in the function which would be difficult to optimize without numba. Unfortunately Random.sample does not work with numba. Do you know an efficient workaround for that?

Comment: Do you mean the function that calls `comb` needs numba to work? I can get it working with numba or multiprocessing, another speedup approach, but both were slower than the solution I provided when I tested them. If it's faster not to use numba do you still need it for this particular function? A 6x speed up seems worth dropping it if possible

Comment: Yes, unfortunately at the current state of my code I need comb to work with numba. Could you maybe add a version for that? Maybe I can make use of the non numba code later. Generally speaking,  for me it is strange that it is slower with the numba decorator.

Comment: Yeah, overall my results with numba seem to be hit or miss. Simple code tends to beat optimized complex code in my experience. I can add in the numba version for you see. It's possible your overall code would benefit from dropping numba and reducing complexity but it'd be up to you to decide if refactoring is worth it or not, especially without a guarantee of improved performance. I will say your native solution without numba was super slow though, 466 seconds vs .4

Comment: I probably really have to think about it then. It’s always interesting to see the possible performance jumps in python. For now it would be really helpful for me if you would add a numba version.

Comment: just added the numba version. Cleaner but no faster than your original

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I use numba 0.51 and on my machine your  numba version (0.43s) and your non-numba version (0.38s) are both much faster and comparable in time with each other!

Comment: One more question: In your code, it seems to me, that in each iteration only two numbers are chosen to recombine. Is that correct? In my code, in each iteration, for all N numbers we choose two random numbers which are recombined.

Comment: In that case your code would actually be much slower :/

Comment: Yeah, I'm i've been messing with it a bit this morning. The two in my code are equivalent and show numba doesn't always beet a native solution but I'm I'll pull the answer down until it beats your benchmark. BTW is your code suppose to return a list of the same number repeated 1000 times? I was looking at the len of the output

Answer (score 3):

One obvious improvement is the repeated calculations of `N-1` and `1<<l - 1` -- those can be calculated once outside the loop and put in variables.

Another wasted effort is the triple initialization of `intList_temp`. There is no reason to set it to 0, set it to `intList`, then set it to the actually calculated values.

Also that `while` loop to ensure the values are distinct is unnecessary. There's plenty of code out there to generate two distinct random numbers with just two random calls. (Hint: if the first random number is chosen arbitrarily, how many valid choices are there for the second random number?)

But I don't think either of these will make much of a difference in speed.

Have you profiled this?

Comment: Predefining N-1 and 1<<l - 1 makes no measurable difference. In Numba I think there is no faster way to copy a list. Also the possibilites to generate two random numbers is limited.

Comment: How does profiling works?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming) https://toucantoco.com/en/tech-blog/tech/python-performance-optimization https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213687/python-how-to-profile-code-written-with-numba-njit-decorators

Answer (score 2):

```
for x3 in range(N):
            intList_temp[x3] = intList[x3]
```

and

```
for x3 in range(N):
            intList[x3] = intList_temp[x3]
```

look pretty messy, I'm not proficient in python, but there should be an implementation of copying a vector much faster.

Comment: Which one is faster in numba?

Comment: `intList_temp = intList[:]` also does the job but seems to be a tiny bit slower